# Laravel "Method does not exist" but only online.

Tags: jquery-mobile, laravel

I have a view (mobilepage2) with a button "next". The frontend is jquery mobile the backend is laravel. I only have one controller.

When i click the "next" button i get the error:

```
{"error":{"type":"BadMethodCallException","message":"Method [testfunction] does not exist.","file":"\/home\/safety\/domains\/safetyanalyse.nl\/public_html\/dev-sac\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Controller.php","line":229}}
```

The strange thing is that my app works fine and shows no error in my localhost. It does show an error on my server online.

**This is my MobileController code**

```
public function testfunction(){
        View::share('waarschijnlijkheid','test');
             View::share('effect','test');
             View::share('blootstellingsfreq','test');
             View::share('risico', 'test');
         return View::make('mobilepages.mobilepage5');
    }
```

**This is a part of my routes.php**

Route::post('gotomobilepage5', 'MobileController@testfunction');

**This is my mobilepage4.blade.php View**

```
@extends('mobilemaster')


@section('content')
{{Form::macro('jradio', function()
{
    return '<input type="radio"';

});
}}
{{Form::macro('jradio2', function($name,$id,$value,$checked)
{
    return '<input type="radio" name='.$name.' id='.$id.' value='.$value.' checked='.$checked.' >';

});
}}

{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'gotomobilepage3', 'method' => 'post')) }}

    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Blootstellingsfrequentie(B)</h3>


        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">

             <label for="radio-choice-v-2a">0 Nooit</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_blootstellingsfreq','radio-choice-v-2a' ,'0',"checked") }} 
             <label for="radio-choice-v-2b">1/2 Zeer zelden {{'(<1x/jaar)'}}</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_blootstellingsfreq','radio-choice-v-2b' ,'0.5',"") }} 
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2c">1 Zelden{{'(jaarlijks)'}} </label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_blootstellingsfreq','radio-choice-v-2c' ,'1',"") }} 
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2d">2 Soms{{'(maandelijks)'}}</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_blootstellingsfreq','radio-choice-v-2d' ,'2',"") }}
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2e">3 Af en toen{{'(wekelijks)'}}</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_blootstellingsfreq','radio-choice-v-2e' ,'3',"") }}
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2f">6 Regelmatig {{'(dagelijks)'}}</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_blootstellingsfreq','radio-choice-v-2f' ,'6',"") }}
              <label for="radio-choice-v-2g">10 Voortdurend</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_blootstellingsfreq','radio-choice-v-2g' ,'10',"") }}

    </fieldset>


    </div>
     <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Effect(E)</h3>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
             <label for="radio-choice-v-2a">0 Geen</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_effect','radio-choice-v-2a' ,'0',"") }} 
             <label for="radio-choice-v-2b">1 Gering</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_effect','radio-choice-v-2b' ,'1',"") }} 
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2c">3 Belangrijk</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_effect','radio-choice-v-2c' ,'3',"") }} 
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2d">7 Ernstig</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_effect','radio-choice-v-2d' ,'7',"") }}
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2e">15 Zeer Ernstig</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_effect','radio-choice-v-2e' ,'15',"") }}
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2f">40 Ramp</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_effect','radio-choice-v-2f' ,'40',"") }}
    </fieldset>

    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Waarschijnlijkheid(W)</h3>

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">


            <label for="radio-choice-v-2a">1/10 Bijna niet denkbaar</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_waarschijnlijkheid','radio-choice-v-2a' ,'0.1',"") }} 
             <label for="radio-choice-v-2b">1/4 Praktisch onmogelijk</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_waarschijnlijkheid','radio-choice-v-2b' ,'0.25',"") }} 
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2c">1/2 Denkbaar, maar onwaarschijnlijke</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_waarschijnlijkheid','radio-choice-v-2c' ,'0.5',"") }} 
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2d">1 Onwaarschijnlijk, mogelijk in grensgeval</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_waarschijnlijkheid','radio-choice-v-2d' ,'1',"") }}
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2e">3 Ongewoon</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_waarschijnlijkheid','radio-choice-v-2e' ,'3',"") }}
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2f">6 Zeer wel mogelijk</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_waarschijnlijkheid','radio-choice-v-2f' ,'6',"") }}
              <label for="radio-choice-v-2g">10 Te verwachten</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_waarschijnlijkheid','radio-choice-v-2g' ,'10',"") }}


    </fieldset>


    </div>
    {{Form:: submit("VERDER")}}
         {{ Form::close() }}
```

As you can see my testfunction exists. What could be the problem? :(

Comment: It exists locally, but has the latest files actually reached the server?

Answer (score 0):

Try `composer dump-autoload` and/or `php artisan optimize` on the webserver to make sure that it is seeing all autoloaded/compiled classes.

Comment: you don't need to do `composer dump-autoload` for controllers even if it is nested with namespace.